# Drop 1st element of {#a, #b, #c} &

Tags: expression-manipulation, slot

I pass the following to a function:

```
{#a, #b, #c} &
```

These are keys that are used in a list of associations.
There are instances where I want to pass only the last 2 elements, such as:

```
{#b, #c} &
```

Right now, I just rewrite it.  But it seems like there should be a way to do this by getting rid of the first slot.

I looked at the full form and see that it's:

```
FullForm[{#a, #b, #c} &]
```

> ```
> Function[List[Slot["a"], Slot["b"], Slot["c"]]]
> ```

I thought I could somehow get inside and drop `Slot["a"]`, but can't seem to do it. I tried replacing `Slot["a"]` with a blank, but I'm left with a comma at the beginning of the list. I also tried `Apply` to change `Function` to `List` and doing it in the result. I couldn't.

Is there any way to get rid of the first element, `#a`, without rewriting the expression?

Comment: Instead of a blank you could replace `Slot["a"]->Nothing`. You'll get this `Nothing` in the resulting function object, but once the function is applied, `Nothing` will collapse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could pass it to `Delete`:

```
Delete[#, {1, 1}] &[{#a, #b, #c} &]
```

> {#b, #c} &

Answer (score 5):

```
foo = {#a, #b, #c} &;

foo[[{1}, 2 ;;]]
```

> {#b, #c} &

or, but only because we know there won't be any side effects:

```
Evaluate /@ Rest /@ foo
```

> {#b, #c} &

or

```
foo /. {_Slot, rest__Slot} :> {rest}
```

At the end consider using an operator form of a `KeyDrop`

```
bar = KeyTake[{"a", "b", "c"}];

(Rest /@ bar)@<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 1, "c" -> 1|>
```

> <|"b" -> 1, "c" -> 1|>

Comment: I accepted Coolwater's answer because it solved my problem simply.  I appreciate the extra insight that your answer provided.  Actually, I'll have to spend more time to really understand it though.

Comment: @MitchellKaplan sure, btw, can you give a little insigth into how do you use it? Because it feels like a XY problem, maybe there is a better way anyway.

Comment: I use a lot of lists of associations and very often I have to sum things by one or more keys.  Why I asked this question:  I work in reinsurance.  My list has, among other things: treaty, effective date, line of business, IBNR.  I'm estimating IBNR by all 3, but it has to balance to the total IBNR for effective/line.  I need to sum both by all 3, but also by only effective/line.  I call a function that does this, and I want to adjust the keys I'm using to eliminate treaty when I'm summing over just effective/line.  Left some detail out to fit answer into comment.